# Determine missing translations in RESX files

Tags: c#, resx

For my globalized C# Windows Forms projects I set the designer value **Localizable** to true to store my default labels automatically into resx files.

My question is: Is there a build-in way or setting to determine and log that

> ResourceManager.GetString("TranslatedLabel", resourceCulture);

wasn't able to find a translation for given resourceCulture and therefore took value from invariant resx file?
It would be nice to have these issues reported within an error log.

Till now I can only find projects that compare resx files and try to find missing keys (e.g. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/322037/Localization-Sync).
But for those tools you need to take care of every single component that is translated. So the possibility to miss one is way to high.

Comment: Anything is possible with the right tools.  Most any professional localization service uses Passolo, pretty sure it has this kind of consistency checking built-in.  Whether you should buy the tool or the service is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

One way to find missing ResX entries is by using [ResEx](http://resex.codeplex.com/). This is a VS extension that displays resources in different languages side-by-side and highlights missing entries in red. You can also filter the view to only show resources with missing entries.

Answer (score 1):

Since ResEx (mentioned by [theDmi](/users/219187)) isn't easy installable, because you could only download the archived project from Codeplex, I want to recommend [ResXManager](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TomEnglert.ResXManager).